# Tomcat + CGI: only works when I'm logged in - How to persist user/privileges?

Tags: tomcat, cgi

Apache Tomcat 5.5 with CGI [enabled](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/cgi-howto.html).

While I am logged in to their server (through SSH), I can start Tomcat, and then I can visit hello.pl in a web browser and "It works!"

But, as soon as I log out from the shell, then the browser no longer works: the next time I call hello.pl from a browser, I just get a blank page. To get the page to work again, I have to restart Tomcat, and stay logged in via SSH. Once I log out of SSH (or if my session times out), then the browser seems to lose the privilege to run the page.

In tomcat.log, I see messages like:

> INFO 2012-04-01 12:05:11,778 [localhost].[/gat] - cgi: runCGI (stderr):perl: no user 12094387

It's probably something obvious, but I am stuck. How would I persist the user/privileges so that CGI works even if I log out of SSH?

Answer (score 0):

The os shuts down the tomcat when you disconnect (or get disconnected). One way to avoid this is to start with [nohup](http://ss64.com/bash/nohup.html)

For example:

```
nohup $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/start.sh &
```